# Git pull error - \ store: store: command not found

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to use git pull with amazon codecommit according to this page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html

It pulls data and works fine, but I keep getting this error:

```
D:\path\project>git pull
\ store:  store: command not found
Already up to date.
```

I tried re-setting the profiles, uninstalling and reinstalling git bash, and some other stuff but nothing works. My config files are:

**C:\Users\user\.aws\credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxx
```

**C:\Users\user\.aws\config**

```
[default]
region = ca-central-1
output = json
```

**C:\Users\user.gitconfig**

```
[credential]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

Comment: Do you have other Git aliases installed somehow somewhere?

Comment: Tangentially, `$@` without quotes is basically always wrong. You either mean `"$@"` or `"$*"` (probably the former).

Comment: Something is trying to run the " store" command (note leading space embedded in the command), instead of the `git credential-store` or `git credential-whatever store` command. I don't know what's doing that though. But there is no such command—nobody creates commands that have a leading space as they're so <adverb> hard to type—so you get that error message.